# Is there any difference between "to drive sales" and "to boost sales"?

Tags: meaning

I feel the former falls more into the idea of conducting the customers towards sales opportunities, while the latter relates more to multiplying sales.

I wonder if this perception would make any sense within both marketing jargon and general usage.

Thanks!

Comment: They're both metaphors, but different ones. One treats _sales_ as a mass noun like _water_ or _sand_ and talks about filling a container with _sales_ so that the level goes up when the sales increase (that's the origin of all `UP` IS `MORE` semantics). The other one is the shepherd metaphor; sheep are stupid and must be driven by someone, usually by fear, to where they can be sheared or slaughtered profitably (goats, by contrast, are smart and must be led to the same fate).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference between “to drive sales” and “to boost sales”?

There are very, very few true synonyms in English. The guidance is, "If it is a different word, it has a different meaning. Each word and phrase carries its own nuance."

To drive = to propel, and describes a motive force behind something that pushes it in a reasonably consistent manner in a given direction - positive or negative. "Health fears drove down the sale of cigarettes." / "Stories of a madman with a gun drove people from the area."

A boost (and hence the verb) is something that is additional. It is solely concerned with **increasing** a force - often suddenly and forcefully. "Sales had been going well, but well-placed advertising boosted them to record levels."

The clearest idea of "boost" is probably in aeronautics where supplementary rockets are attached to a plane boost the speed.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *drive* often refers to the force/reason behind/pushing sales in one direction or the other. We find boost used for *stimulate/make something increase*, for instance, in "What can we do to boost sales?" *Drive* is often used with *up* or *down*, whereas *boost* can be used with *up* (*boost up* something/*boost* something *up*) but not *down*— you can only *boost* upwards.

**drive** (v.)

> to press or force into an activity, course, or direction
> *The drug habit drives addicts to steal.*
>
> To give shape or impulse to
> *factors that drive the business cycle*  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)

The original meaning of *drive* was *move by force* hence **impel**:

> To force (people or animals) to move on before one, or flee away from
> one, by blows or intimidation; to urge on or **impel** with violence
> (OED)

**boost** (v.)

> INCREASE, RAISE
>
> *plans to boost production*
> *an extra holiday to boost morale* [m-w](https://www.google.com/search?q=drive%20sales%20boost%20sales&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=drive%20sales%20boost%20sales&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60.2808j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

*Drive up* can be used with the meaning of *increase/raise/boost*, but *drive* alone usually can't.

---

> But there is obviously little competition involved when both buyer and
> sellers have every incentive to **drive** prices upward. ["Oil Prices
> and Phase II"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oil_Prices_and_Phase_II/KuWUi83V9lMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22drive%20prices%22&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover)

> The storing of corn in the short - crop areas would **drive** prices
> higher than they would have been if the high loan had not been in
> effect, so that ... [G. S. Shepard; *Controlling Corn and Hog Supplies
> and Prices*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Controlling_Corn_and_Hog_Supplies_and_Pr/u78oOY86Gl4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22drive%20prices%22&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover)

> Farm prices for corn fell to $ 57 a ton in September as a record -
> high corn crop in 1986 and poor export prospects continued to
> **drive** prices **lower**. [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drive%20prices%20lower%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvIEQqbn3DWE9QsoZtB2dVuAKYm-Lw%3A1630247819245&ei=i5srYY6XDsSh5NoPlbWomAI&oq=%22drive%20prices%20lower%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1l2.76846.77553.0.77815.6.6.0.0.0.0.108.523.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.441....0.GjiHTPw8lW0) [See this search for examples with "drive lower"]
> See [ref.](http://chasing%20too%20few%20slaughter%20facilities%20,%20have%20combined%20to%20drive%20down%20prices%20received%20by%20producers%20nearly%2015%20percent%20below%20the%20average%20of%20the%201990%27s) for "drive down."

> This essential guide will teach you how to use voice over effectively
> to connect with your target audience, **boost** sales and give your
> brand a personality [S. Brogden; *Boost Your Sales With a Professional
> Voice Over*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Boost_Your_Sales_With_A_Professional_Voi/sheRAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=boost%20sales&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)

> The permanent clerks had, through an informal understanding, agreed
> not to **boost up** sales. [V.S.P. Rao and V Hari Krishna;
> *Management: Text and Cases*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Management/IKN-4sybKiAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22boost%20up%20sales%22&pg=PA839&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Tempted to agree but I feel that there is some business jargon at work here - i.e. an idiomatic usage of "drive" that may be unique to "drive sales."  The first couple google hits suggest to me that "drive" in this case stands in for something like "drive up" which is very close to "boost."

Comment: I don't think you would say "What can we do to drive our sales?" rather than "What can we do to drive up our sales?" But  *drive* alone is probably understood as *drive up.* "The warm weather is driving sales."

Comment: "Drive our sales" - no.  I think MBA-speak is just "drive sales."  Could be a US-phenomenon.

Comment: *Factors that drive the business cycle* is up and down.  The OP asks about general usage also. *The drug habit drives addicts to steal* "Drive ... to *verb*]" is more (+) of the verb.

Answer (score 0):

Something is said to drive sales in English.

For example:
Higher demand for sneakers due to good weather is driving sales steeply upward.

**Driving** in business usually means **pushing.**

**Whereas boost is less strong and just means strengthening.**

For example:
Although higher demand for sneakers is boosting [causing them to rise a bit more] our sales in Asia, our worldwide sales are being driven by the very high numbers of teens starting to buy their own footwear.

sales driver = what makes sales have the level they have
sales booster = what is causing sales to rise a bit more

drive, driving is like a motorized vehicle carrying a load.
boost, boosting is like a device that strengthens an existing force or causes an X  to rise or move forward.

[I have not provided dictionary definitions.]

Answer (score 0):

The difference is subtle. It is the difference between causing something to happen (sometimes in a negative sense) and helping something to increase.

> **drive**
> **4** *[with object]* (of a fact or feeling) compel (someone) to act in a particular way, especially one that is considered undesirable or
> inappropriate.
>      **4.3** Cause (something abstract) to
> happen or develop.
>               
> <sub>‘the consumer has been driving the economy for a number of
> years’</sub>
>              <sub>‘we
> need to allow market forces to drive growth in the telecommunications
> sector’</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *drive*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/drive)</sub>

> **boost**
> **1** Help or encourage (something) to increase or improve.
>        <sub>‘a range of measures to boost tourism’</sub>
>       <sub>‘A recent study in Costa Rica found that
> preserving forest fragments around coffee plantations could boost crop
> yields and increase income.’</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *boost*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/boost)</sub>

Here are some examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

**Drive** (swap in *cause* for *drive*):

> *Additional 5G phones, coupled with more carrier coverage, could drive sales a bit as well in future quarters.*
>  <sub>MAG
> *TechCrunch*</sub>
>
> *It was just one part of the massive effort by the pharmaceutical industry to drive sales of antidepressants, antipsychotics and other
> psychotropic drugs to treat poor children, often for uses never
> approved by federal regulators.*
>  <sub>NEWS *Denver Post*</sub>
>
> *It suggested they did expect that they could count on this conspicuous conservation effect to drive sales.* 
>  <sub>WEB
> *Freakonomics*</sub>
>
> <sub>[More
> examples](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100464095)</sub>

**Boost** (swap in *help increase* for *boost*):

> *I thought some extra holiday cheer might boost sales.*
>  <sub>FIC *Analog Science Fiction & Fact*</sub>
>
> *It’s that kind of enthusiasm retailers hope will boost sales in what is sure to be a tough holiday shopping season.*
>  <sub>SPOK *CBS
> News*</sub>
>
> *I agree that ebooks and mp3s have helped boost sales for a lot of writers and musicians, but it is also easy for that source of income
> to end up online for free as illegal downloads (much to our
> dismay).*
>  <sub>BLOG David Gaughran</sub>
>
> <sub>[More
> examples](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100464100)</sub>